# Memory allocation in arrays in C

Tags: arrays, c

I have a doubt regarding memory allocation to the arrays in C. Like in this snippet I assigned the array size 4 but in the next line, I accessed a location that is not part of the array but still there is no error in execution.I don't understand how it is working.

```
int main()
{  int arr[4];
   arr[5] = 35;
   printf("%d\n",arr[5]);
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: The behavior of undefined behavior is undefined.  Do not expect anything.  Also, C++ is not C.  Do not tag C questions as C++, please.

Comment: An array is allocated at runtime by allocating some space in the memory. In the above case, it might be possible that the adjacent memory location was free and as a result you were able to store a value in it. It might not be the case everytime.

Comment: C doesn't have any kind of bounds-checking. Going out of bounds leads to [*undefined behavior*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior), and it's your responsibility as the programmer to make sure that never happens.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude: C does have bounds checking.  Annex K is literally called “Bounds-checking interfaces.”

Answer (score 2):

C will not prevent you from accessing memory you should not access. There is no safety barrier, no blinking lights or warning sirens. It's just a sheer drop off a cliff with not even so much as a railing in the way.

Remember when writing C code: **It's your job as the programmer to ensure you're not going out of bounds.**

Anything out of bounds is termed *undefined behaviour* which is akin to driving your car off the road. You might just end up on some grass, or you might careen off a mountain. It's dangerous and unless you know exactly what you're doing you shouldn't do it.

There are cases where you know something the compiler doesn't and C won't get in the way. When writing embedded software on extremely limited systems this may be the case, but normally it isn't.

Comment: And the reasoning: C++ has a policy of not making a program pay for behaviour it doesn't ask for. Checking for running off the end of the buffer requires checking. While an attentive enough compiler could catch this one and raise a warning (not a required behaviour, so don't expect it) in the general case the test needs to be performed at runtime, and that has a performance cost on each and every array access. A correct program will never write out of bounds, so checking the bounds would be a performance penalty for a correct program.

Comment: @user4581301 Roughly the same holds for C, which is what I believe this question is about. C++ does do *some* checking in some cases.

Comment: Good point. I got pulled here by the C++ tag.

Answer (score 2):

Accessing an array out of bounds in C and C++ is "undefined behavior", meaning the compiled executable *does not guard against these errors*, and "anything could happen". This means the program could crash, or worse, keep going and subtly corrupt memory. In your example, try this:

```
int main()
{
    int arr[4];
    int x = 0;

    arr[4] = 35;
    printf("%d\n", x);
    return 0;
}
```

If things are placed on the stack one after the other, the `printf` should print `35` for x, even though we modified `arr[4]`. It just happened that `x` was in the adjacent memory location. It could also very well print something else - it's undefined behavior.

Answer (score 0):

The `arr[5]` you're accessing is outside of the allocated space for your `arr` array in the stack memory. For every C program, there is a block of memory created for the stack memory (see [here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/memory-layout-of-c-program/) for details regarding the memory layout of the C program) you can access and write the data in that address `arr[5]` but it will cause undefined behavior such as overriding a stack register (see [here](http://www.ee.nmt.edu/%7Eerives/308L_05/The_stack.pdf) for more info on the stack register/pointer) depending on different architecture

Comment: Careful there. Note the "A typical memory representation of C program" at the beginning of the first link. Little of what is discussed is required by the C standard. These are implementation details. It's pretty rare to see an implementation not based on stack and heap, but what of multi-threaded programs with multiple stacks? Kind of makes a mess of the whole stack at top concept.